# How to detach a session in Gnome terminal with keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

With the mouse, terminal tabs can be detached by highlighting a tab, right-clicking and selecting the said option. I'm more or less a keyboard-only user and thus this feature is inaccessible to me at the time.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on which `gnome-terminal` version you're using and what settings you use but `Detach Current Tab` doesn't have a bound keyboard shortcut.

However, you can bind one manually in

Rocky 9: **Settings > Configure Keyboard Shortcuts > Detach Current Tab**

Ubuntu: **Edit > Preferences > Shortcuts > Detach Tab**

The actual location of **Keyboard Shortcuts** may vary depending on the Version/Distribution.

Comment: Thank you for this answer as it's quick and to the point. I bound `ctrl-d`.